# Compute Engine VM instance group got wiped out?

Tags: google-compute-engine, instance, gce-instance-group

I'm new to GCE and want to migrate my web site there. I created a VM instance group hoping. I installed all the packages and set it up a couple days ago. But today I noticed my VM instance group has a different name (postfix, to be exact), and the disk is flushed empty. Is it possible to restore its status, or at least make sure it won't get wiped out again? I'm so surprised that GCE wiped out everything and I wonder if I'm missing something during setup.

A few details in case they are related:

- I'm using a trusty image for the VM.
- The cloud storage is chosen to be a regular persistent disk.
- It was working with emphemeral IP, and yesterday I started to use Cloud DNS to host my domain. I should have used a static IP, but that mistake shouldn't cause the VM instance group to be flushed...
- I'm using cloud sql as the database service.
- Maybe I should just use VM instance, given I don't have much traffic now?

Any help will be greatly appreciated~

Comment: Did you create group from command line ? 
I would recommend beginning with a single instance and if needed moving to a load balanced solution. 
Please note that instance-group are in beta and is not covered by any SLA.
Could you please provide the output of: gcloud preview instance-groups --zone ZONE list ?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using single instance then.